# I have lost part of text of problem condition.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-set-theory

I have the only last sentence. Prove that $X \approx X \times \{ x \}$ for every set$X$ and every object $x$.

**Question.** What does mean the $\approx ?$ That there exist a biective map between the two sets  $X$ and  $X \times \{ x \}$?

Comment: It can mean a lot of things, but most likely that there is a bijection $X \leftrightarrow X\times\{x\}$...
This has a dead simple constructive answer, though: $a \mapsto (a, x)$ for any $a\in X$ and $(a,x) \mapsto a$ for any $(a,x) \in X\times\{x\}$ suffice and are trivially bijective (The easiest should be to show injectivity of both and inversion property).

Comment: thank you. Yes, if it means bijection  then it is simple problem.

Comment: I don't think there should be an other sentence, since this only sentence is enough - if one assume that $\approx$ mean isomorphism of sets.